# VS2010 Execute unit test (bug)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

When I click on my unit test and do "Execute test" in context menu. The test result wont start the good test, like it won't see my new test and restart my last test again and again. What is wrong with my configuration.

Does anybody experience the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Answer (score 0):

I experience a similar bug with my regular projects. Say I have an open file in VS's text editor, and that file belongs to project A, which is a dll. Then I right-click project B, which is an exe, and select Debug->Start New instance. Sometimes (not always), VS will attempt to start project A, so I get an error like "Can't start a project with output type of Class Library".

When this happens, I open a file from project B and keep it as the active one while I start project B. That works around the issue. So, try to open a file from the test you wanna run and keep it active while you run it from the context menu. I guess this bug is affecting tests execution as well. I thought of submitting a bug report, but I got lazy...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is often very fickle about new tests. There is a configuration setting (Tools -> Options) that determines whether the IDE should pick up new tests as they are written, however it's a bit of a performance pig so the setting is disabled by default.

Visual Studio relies on a VSDMI file to represent meta-data about the tests in the solution. This file is usually updated when the solution is compiled though there are times when the solution-wide analysis doesn't run or it fails to discover new tests. If this file gets out of sync or the test you are trying to run isn't already in the VSDMI then the "run tests in current context" feature doesnt work as expected.  Sometimes it runs a neaby test, sometimes it runs all tests.

To resolve, either enable background discovery of new tests, or open the Test List Editor view and click on the refresh icon in its toolbar. The refresh icon forces a quick recompile and update of the vsdmi.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the context menu options for running tests rarely behave as expected when you add a new test. However, the keyboard shortcuts work much better. Control-R, T runs tests in the 'current context'. If your cursor is in a test method, it runs that method. If it is in a test class, it runs all tests in the class. If it is outside a class I believe it runs all tests in the assembly (or maybe namespace). There are some more shortcuts [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182470.aspx). Note that Control-R, Control-T runs the 'current context' test(s) in the debugger, which is also helpful.